# Lighttpd when running python CGI reports - 403 forbidden - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lighttpd

I am starting a lighttpd service in my ubuntu.My idea here is to serve a python script through CGI.
But, when I do this I get 403 forbidden? Please help how to debug and what am I missing here?

```
vi /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
server.document-root  "/home/httpd"
```

Enable, CGI in lighttpd.

```
vi /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf

server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
    "mod_cgi",
    "mod_rewrite",
)
```

In order to get lighttpd to recognize any python scripts we need to add the following new section at the end of the file.

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/cgi-bin/" {
  cgi.assign = (".py" => "/usr/bin/python")
}
```

Give appropriate permission to the root folder.

```
# chown www-data /home/httpd/cgi-bin
# chgrp www-data /home/httpd/cgi-bin
```

Now, write the hello.py

```
vi /home/httpd/cgi-bin/hello.py

#! /usr/bin/python
#
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
print '<html> <head> <meta-content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>'
print '<title> Raspberry  Pi </title> 
<p> 
for count in range(1,100)
print'Hello&nbspWorld...'
print "/p> <body> </html>
Finally, restart the lighttpd service.
```

## service lighttpd restart

```
  But, when I try to access the page it says- 

403 forbidden
```

Here is my folder with permission /home/httpd.

```
/home/httpd$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Apr  3 17:56 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data root     4096 Apr  3 16:41 html
```

Here is the hello.py

```
/home/httpd/cgi-bin$ ls -l 
total 4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data 244 Apr  3 17:56 hello.py
```

The log says that it is still looking for php, html files rather than my python binary?

```
read(7, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 10.0.2.15\r"..., 4159) = 328
stat("/home/httpd/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/httpd/index.php", 0x7ffee411b9f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/httpd/index.html", 0x7ffee411b9f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/httpd/index.lighttpd.html", 0x7ffee411b9f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
setsockopt(7, SOL_TCP, TCP_CORK, [1], 4) = 0
writev(7, [{iov_base="HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\nContent-"..., iov_len=134}, {iov_base="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"is"..., iov_len=345}], 2) = 479
setsockopt(7, SOL_TCP, TCP_CORK, [0], 4) = 0
ioctl(7, FIONREAD, [0])                 = 0
read(7, 0x5606cf6ceaf0, 4159)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
epoll_ctl(6, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 7, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP, {u32=7, u64=7}}) = 0
accept4(4, 0x7ffee411bc10, [112], SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Comment: Does it have execute permission?   And the commented out server.modules is a typo, right?

Comment: that is a typo here commented out server.modules. I have corrected the question now. What permission am I missing executing? How do I check that? I have done ls -l on /home/httpd now. You can see the owner is www-data for cgi-bin

Comment: You check if www-data has x (and r) permission on the file in question (and all the containing directories).  It apparently has execute permission, so that's not the case.  Do other things work?

Comment: By other things you mean what? it can load the basic page index.html that comes with lighttpd. I tested this before enabling cgi support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the lighttpd error log to see if there is any trace.

Check your SELinux settings, and maybe temporarily disable enforcement to test.

Here's an older question which might be related:
https://serverfault.com/questions/335571/selinux-causes-permission-denied-when-starting-lighttpdfastcgi-via-upstart

If you're interested in more gory details, you can also `strace` the lighttpd process to see what syscall is failing when you make that request.

Comment: I am running this on Ubuntu. Also, how do I attach strace, I am doing like this - sudo strace /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart and it just exits with status 0 i..e successful. How do I attach strace to the daemon so that I can keep seeing what happens when I access that page.

Comment: `strace lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`

Comment: The log still says that it is still looking for html, php files rather than my python file. By the way, what does -D means when we are running lighttpd with option -D.

Comment: When you have a question about a command line option, try running the command line help or the man page.  `lighttpd -h` or `man lighttpd`

Comment: If strace does not show lighttpd trying to access the hello.py or /usr/bin/python, then you have misconfigured lighttpd.conf.  Try simply `cgi.assign = (".py" => "/usr/bin/python")` without the condition wrapping it

Comment: It didn't help, I feel it is not looking for loading the python file. cgi.assign                  = (".py" => "/usr/bin/python")

Comment: Are you making a request for your python file?  `GET / HTTP/1.1` is not a request for hello.py